# Laravel: Only allowing one session per user at a time

Tags: php, session, laravel

Is it possible in Laravel 4 to only allow one session per user at a time?

Eg, so if User logs in and already has other Sessions, those other Sessions are cancelled, preferably with a way to alert them why?

I'm using the Redis session driver on Amazon ElastiCache if that helps as well.

Comment: You can only have one session active at a time, you can only put different data to have several "sessions" simultaneously.

Comment: What do you mean? In Laravel 4 by default, a user can log in multiple times with the same account on different machines and all those Sessions will be valid. I want to make it so once they login, all other Sessions attached to their UserId are cancelled.

Comment: Ok, I understand now, but to solve this you'll need to query your session driver for all sessions connected to given user and delete them. Normally I'd put that in a database and just delete other ones, but in your case I'm not aware of the solution.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yeah, I did similar for my project.

So, you need add to your user model another attribute in this case: last_sessid.

```
public function swapping($user) {
    $new_sessid   = \Session::getId(); //get new session_id after user sign in
    $last_session = \Session::getHandler()->read($user->last_sessid); // retrive last session

    if ($last_session) {
        if (\Session::getHandler()->destroy($user->last_sessid)) {
            // session was destroyed
        }
    }

    $user->last_sessid = $new_sessid;
    $user->save();
}
```

Now, if the user has an active session, and signs in another browser, the first session will be removed.

P.S. Sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: Isn't it just session regeneration? If he has a problem like in GMail, that you can be logged in on 5 machines and he wants to logout user on other 4? I think your code does not solve his problem.

Comment: For example: You logged in chrome, than you open firefox and logged in, then, when you back to chrome and try do smth what need permission only for logged in user, your auth filter will throw exception, or redirect back with error, etc... And for me, this code works perfectly 1 user - 1 session

Comment: But it forbids to allow user to log in simultaneously in several places and then only choose to log out from all other.

Comment: If I correctly understand u, yes you can't choose which session will be removed, but if you want to choose, you should save all session_id of user...

Comment: How can i do this but with only 2 sessións and not allow login into a 3rt sessión.

Comment: `your auth filter will throw exception, or redirect back with error, etc...`- whay would you allow to show errors ?   How to handle it ?

Answer (score 11):

For laravel 5.2 after executing the `make:auth` command you can create the method:`public function authenticated(Request $request,User $user)` in the AuthController.php and in that method you can do what you want after login.
For a single session per user we add to the AuthController at top:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
```

And add the function:

```
public function authenticated(Request $request,User $user){
    $previous_session = $user->session_id;

    if ($previous_session) {
        \Session::getHandler()->destroy($previous_session);
    }

    Auth::user()->session_id = \Session::getId();
    Auth::user()->save();
    return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Remember to add the migration for altering your users table with the session_id column.

Answer (score 3):

This question is much earlier, but someone will be benefited through these easy steps.

The first step is to comment out the:

`\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,`
line from `App\Http` `Kernel.php` class.

Secondly add this line in your login function just after login attempt successfully and before redirection:
`\Auth::logoutOtherDevices(request('password'));`

That's all.

Comment: so simple and easy, thanks for this

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve it like this:

Array of SessionIds in Redis (per user)

example: `user.sessions.[userid] [ .... ]`

in login before filter:

```
foreach (json_decode($redis->get('user.sessions.$userId')) as $sesId) {
   Session::getHandler()->destroy($sesId));
}

// add session to redis
$redis->set('user.sessions.$userId', json_encode([Session::getId()]));
```

This way you can also create a numeric session limit, just destroy up to `NumActiveSessions - MaxSessions` in Redis.