# How can I check if user is already logged in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to "discover" if user is logged in other PC, browser, device, etc.

If the user login in his smartphone (example) and press "Remember login", then try to login in PC, an TokenMismatchException occurs. If he don't press, he can login.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Have a look here, http://stackoverflow.com/a/36350394/4921818

Comment: Great! I'll adapt it to my needs. Thank you!