# Laravel allow user to login in from one device only, allow only one session for each user

Tags: php, laravel, session, redis

I am developing a Laravel application and need to implement a security feature that allows users to log in from only one device at a time. In other words, I want to enforce a single session per user in my application.

I understand that Laravel provides built-in session management functionality but doesn't inherently restrict users from logging in from multiple devices simultaneously. To achieve this requirement, I seek guidance on implementing a solution that ensures a user can only have one active session at a time.

Here are some specific questions I have:

1. How can I detect and prevent multiple logins from the same user
   account?
2. What is the best approach to invalidate previous sessions when a user logs in from a new device?
3. How can I handle cases where a user's session becomes inactive or expires?

I would greatly appreciate any insights or code examples to help me accomplish this task.

This is my current Login method:

```
public function store(LoginRequest $request)
{
    $request->authenticate();

    // Check if the user already has an active session
    $previousSessionId = Redis::get('ga:user_session_id:' . Auth::id());

    if ($previousSessionId) {
        // Destroy the previous session
        Redis::del('ga:user_session_id:' . Auth::id());

        // Logout the user
        Auth::logout();

        return abort(403); // Return an error response indicating that multiple sessions are not allowed
    }

    $request->session()->regenerate();

    $user = Auth::user();
    $sessionId = uniqid(); // Generate a unique session ID

    // Store the unique session ID in Redis
    Redis::set('ga:user_session_id:' . $user->id, $sessionId);

    if (Auth::user()) {
        if (Auth::user()->hasRole('الوصول الى لوحة التحكم')) {
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        } else {
            return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
        }
    }
}
```

Using the previous code, for example, if I logged in using device 1, it logged in successfully. If I logged in using device 2 while device 1 was logged in, it returned 403, but when I refreshed the tab, it logged device 2 as well, and both devices were logged in simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in session management functionality in Laravel to enforce a single session per user. When a user logs in, you can store their session ID in the database or cache. Then, when the same user logs in from another device, you can invalidate their previous session.

```
public function store(LoginRequest $request)
{
    $request->authenticate();

    $user = Auth::user();

    // Get the previous session ID from the cache
    $previousSessionId = Redis::get('user_session_id:' . $user->id);

    if ($previousSessionId) {
        // Delete the previous session data
        session()->getHandler()->destroy($previousSessionId);
    }

    // Store the current session ID in the cache
    Redis::set('user_session_id:' . $user->id, session()->getId());

    $request->session()->regenerate();

    if ($user->hasRole('الوصول الى لوحة التحكم')) {
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    } else {
        return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need add to your user model another attribute in this case: last_sessid
check this

[awnser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27938580/23184314)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something like that, but different. The session will be only valid in the first device after registering the account. If the user tries to login in another device, it will not login, with no more information about the state or situation of the account.

The solution is that, even with user and password, there will be a string generated by the device.

Every time the shared credentials tries to validate in the other device, the first session validated will be untouched only if the user asks the Sysadmin to demote that session to create a new one in another device.

Answer (score -1):

You can implement a middleware and apply it to routes that need to be protected and enforced for single-session-per-user.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class SingleSessionMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        if ($user && $user->session_token !== session('session_token')) {
            Auth::logout();
            return redirect()->route('login')->with('error', 'You have been logged out from other device.');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```